# on the group with automorphism groups of odd order

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be group and $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ be the automorphisms of $G$ and $p$ is an odd prime.

Now does there exist a group such that

$p$ is the smallest  prime that $p \mid |\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$.

and

$G$ has a characteristic subgroup of order $p$.

Thank you

Comment: There exist finite $p$-groups $G$ where every automorphism is central, so every subgroup of the derived subgroup is characteristic, and the automorphism group of $G$ is a $p$-group. You may take several groups of this kind, for different primes, and their direct product will also be an example. But maybe you don't want $G$ to be nilpotent.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Please expalin more for me.